# CSS Table input

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons that I need to be the same width in my table but one is bigger than the other. They were both the same width but I think I changed something and I can't bring it back

```css
body.products table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

body.products input.add[type="button"] {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #27af60;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
}

body.products input.del[type="button"] {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
}

body.products input.submit[type="submit"] {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body class="products">
  <form action="addtable.php" method="GET">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input class="add" type="button" value="Add a Product">
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input class="del" type="button" value="Delete a Product">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <input class="submit" name="prod_submit" type="submit" value="Submit Products">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get `Add a Product` and `Delete a Product` to be the same width or the submit button to be as wide as both of them?

Comment: the submit is fine it takes up 4 cols and has a width of 100% but the add and delete are not the same width. When i inspect element the add td has a bigger width than the delete

Comment: Ahh. Then "Delete a Product" is taking up more room because its content (the text Delete a Product) is longer than the contents of "Add a Product". You will need to make the table size larger than twice what would be the minimum width of "Delete a Product".   Nitin Garg's suggestion of 300px is probably good. But it might change if you change your text size.

Answer (score 1):

Along with table-layout:fixed, you will have to add width as well for example width:300px;

```css
table{
table-layout: fixed;
width:300px;
}    

input.add[type="button"]{

color:white;
width: 100%;
background-color: #27af60;
border: none;
letter-spacing: .8px;

}

input.del[type="button"]{

color:white;
width: 100%;
background-color: #c0392b;
border: none;
letter-spacing: .8px;
}

input.submit[type="submit"]{

color:white;
width: 100%;
background-color: gray;
border: none;
letter-spacing: .8px;
}
```

```html
 <table>  
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" ><input class="add" type="button" value="Add a Product"></td>
            <td colspan="2" ><input class="del" type="button" value="Delete a Product"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input class="submit" name="prod_submit" type="submit" value="Submit Products"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have removed the class from the body in your html. You could add it back in and it looks like it would work or you could add the products class to your table and change your CSS a bit. Assuming you want the Submit button to be as wide as the other two.

```
   table.products {
    table-layout: fixed;
    }    

    table.products input.add[type="button"]{

    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #27af60;
    border: none;
    letter-spacing: .8px;

    }

    table.products input.del[type="button"]{

    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c0392b;
    border: none;
    letter-spacing: .8px;
    }

    table.products input.submit[type="submit"]{

    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    border: none;
    letter-spacing: .8px;
    }
<table class="products">  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input class="add" type="button" value="Add a Product"></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input class="del" type="button" value="Delete a Product"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input class="submit" name="prod_submit" type="submit" value="Submit Products"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: i had edited the question to add the relevant body tag in and demonstrate the issue as a runnable snippet, but it got edited back out. I have re-added the snippet so the `body` tag has the appropriate class and you can see how the behaviour the OP is describing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of the `tds` to 50% each, otherwise they will naturally size to their content and `Delete` will be bigger than `Add`. You can do this by adding the following CSS:

```
body.products table tr:first-child > td {
  width:50%;
}
```

```css
body.products table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

body.products table tr:first-child > td {
  width:50%;
}

body.products input.add[type="button"] {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #27af60;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
}

body.products input.del[type="button"] {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
}

body.products input.submit[type="submit"] {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body class="products">
  <form action="addtable.php" method="GET">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input class="add" type="button" value="Add a Product">
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input class="del" type="button" value="Delete a Product">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <input class="submit" name="prod_submit" type="submit" value="Submit Products">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```